# JsonSchema validation of string containing two objects and one bool?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema, jobjectformatter

I'm looking to to reuse code from a project that looks like the first code block but need some help **to do a json schema** (second code block) that instead contains two objects and one bool and not just one object?

Guessing som sort of allOf but not quite sure how to use it.

```
string schemaJson = @"{
            'description': 'onlyOneObject',
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'personId': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength' : 6 },
                'code': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength' : 3 }                       
             },
             'required' : [ 'personId' , 'code' ]
         }";
        
        JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);
```

so something like this is what I need your expert help with as I'm not quite sure about the syntax.

```
 string schemaJson = @"{
            'description': 'firstObject',
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'personId': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength' : 6 },
                'code': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength' : 3 }                       
             },
             'required' : [ 'personId' , 'code' ]

            'description': 'secondObject',  ??? Can I write the second object like this???
            'type': 'object',
            'properties': {
                'name': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength' : 6 },
                'code2': { 'type': 'string', 'minLength' : 3 }                       
             },
             'required' : [ 'name' , 'code2' ]

             'description': 'yeahOrNay',
             'type': 'bool'
             something something for bool???
         }";
```

Comment: Please try to share with us a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you please share with us the sample json(s) against which you want to perform the validation?

Comment: *not perform an actual validation* >> `bool schemaValid = tmp.IsValid(schema, out errors)` I want to help you and I need more context but If you don't want to provide that then have a great day....

Comment: @JoBo Please remember to be nice. You may want to re-read the StackOverflow Code of Conduct: https://stackoverflow.com/conduct

Comment: As for your question, you have not provided enough information for me to provide an answer. Please share examples of data you want to validate. "I'm trying to create a json schema not perform an actual validation" in which case, you need to explain why you want a JSON Schema. JSON Schema is desgined for validation of JSON data. If you aren't using it for validation, you'll likely also need to provide the library you are using, because any non-validation is implementation specific. And before you suggest I don't know JSON Schema, you may wish to check who published the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here was the answer I was looking for............**structure of a schemaJson containing two objects and a bool**. (not every single prop to validate as it was the structure I was after)

Cudos to myself as some deemed it impossible to answer based on the given information :)

```
 string schemaJson = @"{
           'description': 'myObject',
           'type': 'object',
           'properties': {
           'firstObject': {
                'type': 'object',
                'properties': {
                'NUMBER': { 'type': 'integer' } 
                }
            },
           'secondObject': { 
                'type': 'object',
                'properties': {
                'NUMBER': { 'type': 'integer' } 
                }
            },
           'yeahOrNay': { 'type': 'boolean' }                        
            },
        }";
```